# Lazy<T> breaks when exception is handled

Tags: c#

Maybe I'm missing something but why does visual studio break execution to tell me an exception has occured even though its handled?

Yes, unchecking user-unhandled exception fixes the problem, but why is a handled exception being called a unhandled exception?

```
Lazy<int> lazyCount = new Lazy<int>(() => { throw new NotImplementedException(); }, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
Func<int> valueGenerator = () => { throw new NotImplementedException(); };

try
{
    int value = lazyCount.Value;
}
catch (NotImplementedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Breaks");
}

try
{
    int value = valueGenerator();
}
catch (NotImplementedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Breaks");
}

try
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
catch (NotImplementedException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doesn't break");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean by break? Does the debugger/IDE crash? Is the exception not caught?

Comment: @BoldClock Break as in breaks the execution to tell me an exception has occurred. I thought it was the correct terminology.

Comment: In the first case the exception is not handled in the method that it's thrown in (the delegate).

Comment: The implementation of Lazy<> is getting in the way here.  The exception is thrown in code that is *not* Your Code.  Easy to see from the exception's StackTrace property, you didn't write the b_0() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're annoyed by the dialog I would recommend disabling the Exception Assistant (I'm not sure what it is assisting).

> Tools -> Options -> Debugging

Under this options menu you can disable the Exception Assistant, and control various other debugging features (Just My Code, etc).

[As @Michael Kennedy noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194074/lazyt-breaks-when-exception-is-handled/6194103#6194103) you can goto `Debug -> Exception...` (also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), click `Find` and uncheck *Thrown* for the offending exception.

Comment: Still breaks, just has a plain text box with less verbose details.

Comment: @Will: updated to address what I now realize you're asking for.

Comment: 'Thrown' was already unchecked. I had to also uncheck 'User-unhandled'. I'm still confused why this only happens with Lazy<T>.

Comment: @Will: I did some tests and it looks like @Maxim is right (he commented on your post).

Comment: @Will: are you on an Express version of VS?

Comment: Ok, you can go under `Tools -> Options -> Debugging` and disable Just My Code.

Comment: Well that removes the option for 'user-unhandled'.

Comment: Well this fixes my annoyance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Will, FYI, this means you will never break on ANY exceptions (or perhaps only NotImplementedException, if that's what you've selected), even if they have not been handled.  Be sure that this is really the behavior that you want.

Comment: I understood this when I was making the changes. Not really the desired result...

Comment: @Dan: only on rare occasions do I re-enable Just My Code, much smoother experience. Granted I'm weird like that.

Answer (score 3):

The debugger is trying to help you and stop early at the source of an exception. You can always just run it outside the debugger by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> rather than <kbd>F5</kbd> to get it running.

For more granularity, check out the Debug->Exceptions menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: I realize I can run without a debugger and be fine, but I would rather use a debugger to debug my code and not have to resume execution every time a Lazy<T> has an exception intitializing its value. I've looked though debug->Exceptions, nothing stands out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yeah, in that menu you can uncheck "break on throw" for CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
        Func<int> a = () => { throw new NotImplementedException(); };

        try
        {
            //int value = lazyCount.Value;
            a();
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException e)
        {
        }
```

You'll notice that it does *not* break the debugger, even though you're still invoking an anonymous method.

What's happening here is that the LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication instructs the Lazy class to cache the Exception so that multiple calls to Value from different threads will throw the same exception.  My guess is that they have some additional logic that tells the debugger the exception is unhandled the first time it is thrown, so that you have a chance to inspect the exception in its original context before it is cached and later rethrown.  I was going to open up the code in Reflector to see if this is the case, but apparently the free community version of Reflector is no longer free.

Comment: You don't have to use reflector. You can step into .net code like so. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: I guess Lazy<T> is not available though.

Comment: @Will, I was curious, so I went ahead and just opened it up manually in ildasm.  The only thing I notice is that it calls the internal method Exception::PrepForRemoting, which preserves the stack trace for a rethrown exception (the same mechanism used when rethrowing a serialized remoting exception.)  It's possible the debugger is in on this little hack and considers a 'remoted' exception to be unhandled, to help with debugging.